# Custom calculation for sold amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('23/06/2014', 3,  0,  11203659),
('30/06/2014', 7,  1,  11203659),
('07/07/2014', 6,  0,  11203659),
('14/07/2014', 2,  1,  11203659),
('21/07/2014', 5,  0,  11203659),
('28/07/2014', 21, 1,  11203659),
('04/08/2014', 3,  1,  11203659),
('11/08/2014', 9,  1,  11203659),
('18/08/2014', 7,  0,  11203659),
('25/08/2014', 4,  0,  11203659),
('01/09/2014', 2,  0,  11203659),
('08/09/2014', 4,  0,  11203659),
('15/09/2014', 1,  0,  11203659),
('22/09/2014', 3,  1,  11203659),
('29/09/2014', 6,  1,  11203659),
('06/10/2014', 3,  1,  11203659),
('13/10/2014', 4,  1,  11203659)
) as t([Date], SoldAmt, promo, code_article))
```

I try to calculate average sum (SoldAmt)/number od days between the min date and max date rolling back the first 28 days/times in which promo =1 by Article

```
select sum(SoldAmt)/convert(day, Date)
from MyTable 
group by [code article ],Date
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0):

Take a `cte` from you question and try this:

```
SELECT sum(SoldAmt)*1.00/DATEDIFF(day, MIN(convert(date,[Date],104)),MAX(convert(date,[Date],104))) as 'average sum'
FROM cte 
WHERE promo !=1
GROUP BY code_article
```

`WHERE promo !=1` rollback exact 28 days from `DATEDIFF` result.

Result:

```
average sum
---------------------------------------
0.3809523809523

(1 row(s) affected)
```