# Custom calculation for amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
Date      Value promo   item
01/01/2011  626 0   1230
01/02/2011  231 1   1230
01/03/2011  572 1   1230
01/04/2011  775 1   1230
01/05/2011  660 1   1230
01/06/2011  662 1   1230
01/07/2011  541 1   1230
01/08/2011  849 1   1230
01/09/2011  632 1   1230
01/10/2011  906 1   1230
01/11/2011  961 1   1230
01/12/2011  361 0   1230
01/01/2012  461 0   1230
01/02/2012  928 1   1230
01/03/2012  855 0   1230
01/04/2012  605 0   1230
01/05/2012  83  0   1230
01/06/2012  44  0   1230
01/07/2012  382 0   1230
01/08/2012  862 0   1230
01/09/2012  549 0   1230
01/10/2012  632 0   1230
01/11/2012  2   0   1230
01/12/2012  26  0   1230
```

I try to calculate average sum (SoldAmt)/number od days between the min date and max date rolling back the first 28 rows(4 weeks ) in which promo =1 by Article

The smoothing period is 4 weeks on the back regardless of the day discount.

That is to say, if such item is in promotion for a week during the last 4 weeks smoothing is over 5 weeks without regard to the promotion of sales week.

How to calculate the first 4 weeks/28rows data order by time for promo =1?

I try

```
         CREATE TABLE #RollingTotalsExample
(
    [Date]     DATE 
    ,[Value]   INT
    ,promo float 
    ,item int 
);

INSERT INTO #RollingTotalsExample
SELECT '2011-01-01',626,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-02-01',231,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2011-03-01',572,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-04-01',775,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2011-05-01',660,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-06-01',662,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2011-07-01',541,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-08-01',849,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-09-01',632,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-10-01',906,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-11-01',961,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-04-01',775,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-05-01',660,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-06-01',662,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-07-01',541,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-08-01',849,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-09-01',632,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-10-01',906,1,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2016-11-01',961,1,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-12-01',361,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-01',461,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-02-01',928,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-03-01',855,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-04-01',605,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-05-01',83,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-06-01',44,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-07-01',382,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-08-01',862,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-09-01',549,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-10-01',632,0,1230 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-11-01',2,0,1230
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-12-01',26,0,1230;
 SELECT * FROM #RollingTotalsExample;

    -- Rolling twelve month total by using INNER JOIN
    SELECT a.[Date]
        ,Value=MAX(CASE WHEN a.[Date] = b.[Date] THEN a.Value END)
        ,Rolling12Months=CASE
                            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.[Date]) < 12
                            THEN NULL
                            ELSE SUM(b.Value)
                            END
    FROM #RollingTotalsExample a
    JOIN #RollingTotalsExample b ON b.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -11, a.[Date]) AND a.[Date]
    GROUP BY a.[Date]
    ORDER BY a.[Date];
```

Now how to modify the query in order to calculate average sum (SoldAmt)/number od days between the min date and max date rolling back the  28 first  rows data order by time for promo =1 by Article

Comment: This is a good question (upvote from my side), especially due to the copy'n'pasteable test code **with sample data**. There's only one thing missing: the expected output, fitting to the data. Would you plase add this to your question?

Comment: What does it mean rolling back first 12 days ,does this mean,you dont want first 12 days data order by time for promo =1?

Comment: @TheGameiswar yes exactly .

Comment: Right now with this source and output this is simple `where promo = 1`.

Comment: Why do you ask about `SoldAmt` in your question when there is no `SoldAmt` column in your table?   What is it?

Comment: Add your "expected result" to the question - not words - but the result table you expect to get from the query. (You calculate this manually based on he sample data.) Once we have that then we will understand what you are asking for. At the moment we are guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach that requires LAG() which is available from SQL 2012, but note the sample data does not contain "28 distinct days" prior to each date. Also the actual data type being used isn't known (date/smalldatetime/datetime/datetime2) nor is it known if truncating time from date is needed. So with some caveats, this approach creates a series of date ranges for the 28 distinct dates (but is the data doesn't provide these then they are 28 elapsed days). Here is a is a [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0aa5f/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:
(as SQL Server not operating at sqlfiddle)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (theDate timestamp, Value int, promo int, item int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (theDate, Value, promo, item)
VALUES
    ('2011-01-01 00:00:00', 626, 0, 1230),
    ('2011-01-02 00:00:00', 231, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-03 00:00:00', 572, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-04 00:00:00', 775, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-05 00:00:00', 660, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-06 00:00:00', 662, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-07 00:00:00', 541, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-08 00:00:00', 849, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-09 00:00:00', 632, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-10 00:00:00', 906, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-11 00:00:00', 961, 1, 1230),
    ('2011-01-12 00:00:00', 361, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 461, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-02 00:00:00', 928, 1, 1230),
    ('2012-01-03 00:00:00', 855, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-04 00:00:00', 605, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-05 00:00:00', 83, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-06 00:00:00', 44, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-07 00:00:00', 382, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-08 00:00:00', 862, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-09 00:00:00', 549, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-10 00:00:00', 632, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-11 00:00:00', 2, 0, 1230),
    ('2012-01-12 00:00:00', 26, 0, 1230)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      t1.item
    , ranges.theStart
    , ranges.theEnd
    , sum(t1.value)
    , sum(t1.value) / 28 avg
from (
      select
            coalesce(lag(theDay,28) over(order by theDay) , theDay - INTERVAL '28 DAYS') as theStart
          , theDay as theEnd
      from (
            select distinct cast(thedate as date) theDay from Table1
            ) days
      ) ranges
inner join table1 t1 on theDate between ranges.theStart and ranges.theEnd
group by
      t1.item
    , ranges.theStart
    , ranges.theEnd
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0aa5f/1/0)**:

```
| item |                   thestart |                    theend |  sum | avg |
|------|----------------------------|---------------------------|------|-----|
| 1230 | December, 04 2010 00:00:00 | January, 01 2011 00:00:00 |  626 |  22 |
| 1230 | December, 05 2010 00:00:00 | January, 02 2011 00:00:00 |  857 |  30 |
| 1230 | December, 06 2010 00:00:00 | January, 03 2011 00:00:00 | 1429 |  51 |
| 1230 | December, 07 2010 00:00:00 | January, 04 2011 00:00:00 | 2204 |  78 |
| 1230 | December, 08 2010 00:00:00 | January, 05 2011 00:00:00 | 2864 | 102 |
| 1230 | December, 09 2010 00:00:00 | January, 06 2011 00:00:00 | 3526 | 125 |
| 1230 | December, 10 2010 00:00:00 | January, 07 2011 00:00:00 | 4067 | 145 |
| 1230 | December, 11 2010 00:00:00 | January, 08 2011 00:00:00 | 4916 | 175 |
| 1230 | December, 12 2010 00:00:00 | January, 09 2011 00:00:00 | 5548 | 198 |
| 1230 | December, 13 2010 00:00:00 | January, 10 2011 00:00:00 | 6454 | 230 |
| 1230 | December, 14 2010 00:00:00 | January, 11 2011 00:00:00 | 7415 | 264 |
| 1230 | December, 15 2010 00:00:00 | January, 12 2011 00:00:00 | 7776 | 277 |
| 1230 | December, 04 2011 00:00:00 | January, 01 2012 00:00:00 |  461 |  16 |
| 1230 | December, 05 2011 00:00:00 | January, 02 2012 00:00:00 | 1389 |  49 |
| 1230 | December, 06 2011 00:00:00 | January, 03 2012 00:00:00 | 2244 |  80 |
| 1230 | December, 07 2011 00:00:00 | January, 04 2012 00:00:00 | 2849 | 101 |
| 1230 | December, 08 2011 00:00:00 | January, 05 2012 00:00:00 | 2932 | 104 |
| 1230 | December, 09 2011 00:00:00 | January, 06 2012 00:00:00 | 2976 | 106 |
| 1230 | December, 10 2011 00:00:00 | January, 07 2012 00:00:00 | 3358 | 119 |
| 1230 | December, 11 2011 00:00:00 | January, 08 2012 00:00:00 | 4220 | 150 |
| 1230 | December, 12 2011 00:00:00 | January, 09 2012 00:00:00 | 4769 | 170 |
| 1230 | December, 13 2011 00:00:00 | January, 10 2012 00:00:00 | 5401 | 192 |
| 1230 | December, 14 2011 00:00:00 | January, 11 2012 00:00:00 | 5403 | 192 |
| 1230 | December, 15 2011 00:00:00 | January, 12 2012 00:00:00 | 5429 | 193 |
```

NB: For SQL Server

- instead of `theDay - INTERVAL '28 DAYS'` use **dateadd(day,-28,theDay)**

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for cumulative sum for all days excluding first 12 days from mindate...

```
with cte
as
(
select dateadd(day,12,min(date)) as mindate,max(date) as maxdate,
datediff(day,dateadd(day,12,min(date)),max(date)) as n

from #RollingTotalsExample
)
select 
date,
(select sum(value) from #RollingTotalsExample t2 where t2.date<=t1.date) as rollingsum,
promo,
item,
mindate,
maxdate
from 
#RollingTotalsExample t1
join
cte c
on  t1.date >=c.mindate and t1.date<= c.maxdate
order by date
```

--this matches your exact output

```
with cte
as
(
select dateadd(day,12,min(date)) as mindate,max(date) as maxdate,
datediff(day,dateadd(day,12,min(date)),max(date)) as n

from #RollingTotalsExample
)
select 
date,
sum(value) as avgsum,
promo,
item
from 
#RollingTotalsExample t1
join
cte c
on  t1.date >=c.mindate and t1.date<= c.maxdate
where promo=1
group by date,promo,item
order by date
```

---if you are looking for avg: sum/no of days

```
with cte
as
(
select dateadd(day,12,min(date)) as mindate,max(date) as maxdate,
datediff(day,dateadd(day,12,min(date)),max(date)) as n

from #RollingTotalsExample
)
select 
date,
sum(value)/n*1.0 as avgsum,
promo,
item
from 
#RollingTotalsExample t1
join
cte c
on  t1.date >=c.mindate and t1.date<= c.maxdate
where promo=1
group by date,promo,item,n
order by date
```

Comment: How could I get the first 12 rows data order by time for promo =1 ?

Comment: Just sum or cumulative sum or avg

Comment: I am looking to get the first 12 rows(rownumber) data order by time for promo =1  by article

Comment: select  top 12 * from table where promo=1 order by date ?  wont this work

Comment: I have multiple item , I need to have select top 12 * from table where promo=1 order by date by article

Comment: I totally didnt understand  what you are trying to say now.Could you edit the question with the relevant info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105370/discussion-between-test-test-and-thegameiswar).

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no stated/shown "expected result" I am guessing quite a bit. While I have read the words of this question, and [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791038/custom-calculation-for-sold-amount/35791935#35791935), I really don't understand the description. With these reservations I suggest the following:

Result:

```
| item | promo_start |    max_date |  sum | count | avg |
|------|-------------|-------------|------|-------|-----|
| 1230 | Jan 02 2011 | Jan 12 2011 | 7150 |    11 | 650 |
| 1230 | Jan 02 2012 | Jan 12 2012 | 4968 |    11 | 451 |
```

Produced by the following query (using Postgres):

```
select
      item
    , promo_start
    , max(thedate) max_date
    , sum(value)
    , count(distinct thedate)
    , sum(value) / count(distinct thedate) avg
from (
      select *
      from table1 t1
      cross join lateral (
            select min(t2.thedate) promo_start
            from table1 t2
            where promo = 1
            and t1.item = t2.item
            and t2.thedate <= t1.thedate
            and t2.thedate >= t1.thedate - INTERVAL '28 DAYS'
            ) a
      ) d
where promo_start is NOT NULL
group by
      item
    , promo_start
;
```

See this as [a demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c5403/6) (nb: SQL Server is/has not working at that site for several weeks so Postgres used in lieu)

**NB: For SQL Server**

1. instead of `cross join lateral' use **CROSS APPLY**
2. instead of `t1.thedate - INTERVAL '28 DAYS'` use **dateadd(day,-28,t1.thedate)**

The logic is as follows:

1. the cross join lateral (*cross apply*) sub-query locates the minimum date in which an item has been on promotion in the prior 28 days
2. that minimum date is repeated on each row for a promotion affected period
3. only rows that have been affected by a promotion are then selected
4. then the item and promotion start date are used for grouping the selected rows, with aggregates used to calculate average
5. the number of distinct days is used in calculation of the average as sales may not occur on each day within the 28 day period.

*+ I used "theDate" as the column name simply because "date" is too confusing in both code and describing code. I really cannot recommend using "date" as a column name.*

Comment: I am looking to calculate the average of the sum value for the first distinct 28 prior dates not within the 28 day period where promo=1 for each item . It is a calculation for the first distinct 28 prior dates  existing in the table  in which promo =1 by item.

Comment: Is the date/time data stored with ALL times at 00:00:00? (i.e. just dates)?

Comment: Under the data in the question you state: *I try to calculate average sum (SoldAmt)/number od days between the min date and max date rolling back the first 28 rows(4 weeks )* **in which promo =1 by Article** - so you can see how frustrating it is trying to explain your needs by words only, in that statement you did state you needed promo = 1; but in the first comment under my suggestion you state this is not needed.